# Why Windows 7 PC is physically hot but not virtually?

Tags: cpu, temperature, lag, case

I recently noticed my PC's case is somewhat hot on the top after some hours, and is a little lag-ish than before, so I installed "Core Temp" freeware to check the CPU's temperature, I guess it's Ok (since no red alert and low:41 C and Hi: 94 C), 
(my CPU: AMD athlon II X2 250 3.00 GHz )

I'm scanning for viruses and till now found some, 
so can I be assured about my CPU's welfare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case will get warm after being on for a few hours. Core Temp tells you what the CPU says its temperature is, and as long as it's keeping a reasonable amount below its TjMax, you should be OK. Check that your fans on your PC are getting enough ventilation to release the heat - it could just be building up in other places under the case if it's getting really quite hot.

Expect strenuous tasks to heat the CPU up more than usual, that should be safe as long as Core Temp doesn't show critical (red) when you are using your PC normally.

My desktop has a very similar processor to yours, I find that if it's on for hours playing games, converting video, etc. there seems to be a cap that can be reached that causes the processor to reduce its power until a reboot.